# Python access impala with insert error

Tags: python, impala

I used Python 3.5.3 to access impala database with insert operation. 
The command as following:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO user_tbl(ID, USER_IP)VALUES(?,?)" 
values = (89988, '3609:9802:480:77bd:434:2d9a:e204:47b0')

cur.execute(sql, values);
```

but if I run with `cur.execute("INSERT INTO user_tbl(ID, USER_IP)VALUES(89988, '3609:9802:480:77bd:434:2d9a:e204:47b0')")`, the result is successful.

The error is

> "impala.error.HiveServer2Error: AnalysisException: Syntax error in
>   line 1:"
>
> Encountered: STRING LITERAL Expected: CROSS, FROM, FULL, GROUP,
>   HAVING, INNER, JOIN, LEFT, LIMIT, OFFSET,ON, ORDER, RIGHT,
>   STRAIGHT_JOIN, UNION, USING, WHERE, COMMA

Answer (score 0):

Impyla's value substitution format is `%s`, or even `%(name)s`.

It uses `impala.dbapi.paramstyle` equal to `'pyformat'`, and as it is Python DB-API 2.0 compatible, [that means](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle):

> Python extended format codes, e.g. ...WHERE name=%(name)s

Try with

```
sql = "INSERT INTO user_tbl (ID, USER_IP) VALUES (%s, %s)"
values = (89988, '3609:9802:480:77bd:434:2d9a:e204:47b0')    
cur.execute(sql, values)
```

(The `%(name)s` format can be used when `values` is a `dict` instead of a `tuple`.)

Comment: I try the above command:       sql = "INSERT INTO user_tbl (ID, USER_IP) VALUES (%s, %s)"
values = (89988, '3609:9802:480:77bd:434:2d9a:e204:47b0')    
cur.execute(sql, values). It seems as before.

Comment: The issue seems ''3609:9802:480:77bd:434:2d9a:e204:47b0'' which is IPv6 format. If changed to IPv4 or other format. The insert will be success.

Comment: I would file that as a bug with impyla, and go from there. I can't directly see anything wrong with this, so perhaps impyla is doing something odd escaping the string.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the colon `:` separating integers. It messes up data types definition somehow. Some say that this colon has to be escaped, but escaping works incorrectly in insert statements, [open bug for it](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-17358?jql=project%20%3D%20HIVE%20AND%20text%20~%20%22insert%20values%22).

I had a similar issue where I had to store datetime as a string in this format: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss". Integers separated by colon gave me a similar error:

```
Encountered: INTEGER LITERAL
Expected: AND, AS, ASC, BETWEEN,...
```

Some say, you can escape special characters [with their unicode codes](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/173842/how-to-insert-semicolon-in-hive-table.html). I tried replacing `:` with its code `\u003A` and with `\\u003A`, and none of that worked for me.

I ended up replacing colons by dashes or periods.
This also explains why IPv4 (as opposed to IPv6) worked for you @leishton.